# Problems with Rails 4 Asset Pipeline After Pushing to Heroku

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm new to rails and this is the 3rd project that I have deployed to heroku but haven't come across this problem yet. After pushing to heroku, my app isn't loading JS and CSS files both locally and live. I am getting this error message, `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

Here is my application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  </head>

  <body id="page-top" class="index">

    <%= yield %>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>
    <script src="js/agency.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

I have tried to require the js files in application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks

//= require agency
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require cbpAnimatedHeader
//= require cbpAnimatedHeader.min
//= require classie
//= require contact_me
//= require jqBootstrapValidation
```

A common issue that I have found online is changing the asset precompiler to true in config/environments/production.rb

```
  config.assets.compile = true
```

I'm not sure if I am forgetting any code that may help but this one has got me lost!